# Looping, a set of headers and... nothing happening

Tags: php, header, foreach

I'm working on a  project that has file uploads. These files are given a random name and placed out side of the web directory.

I then have a script that retrieves this image based on parameters passed in the URL which works absolutely fine.

However, I made an array of the headers I wanted to pass to the browser and then looped through these with a `foreach` loop and they didn't seem to be setting anything. But, if I set them manually with the `header` function they work! Bizarre!

Now, I do not mind using the `header` function instead of looping through them, but, is there a specific reason that this doesn't work?

I also use the above method to store all my headers in an array and then process them upon delivering the content to the browser, but, I cannot say for certain if they are actually being passed, seeing the aforementioned issue!

Snippet of my code:

```
// Expiry date in seconds, in this instance a year
$expiry_date=   ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 );
// Our headers
$img_headers=   array(
    'Content-Type : ' . $mime,
    'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate',
    //'Cache-control: max-age=' . $expiry_date,
    'Expires:' . gmdate( DATE_RFC1123, time() + $expiry_date ),
    'Pragma: ',
    'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( gmdate( DATE_RFC1123 ), filemtime( $image_path ) ),
    'Content-Length: ' . ( string ) filesize( $image_path ),
    'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $image_name . '"'
);            

/*header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mime, TRUE );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate', TRUE );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( DATE_RFC1123, time() + $expiry_date ) );
header( 'Pragma: ', TRUE );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( gmdate( DATE_RFC1123 ), filemtime( $image_path ) ), TRUE );
header( 'Content-Length: ' . ( string ) filesize( $image_path ), TRUE );*/

// Loop through and set up our headers!
foreach( $img_headers as $new_header )
{
    header( $new_header, TRUE );
}

// Read our image and end the rest of the file execution
return die( readfile( $image_path ) );
```

Anything there that looks out of place?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two methods should be identical.  Maybe the extra space in "Content-Type :" is causing the problem?

Comment: Scrap that, I was a little a head of myself with that comment!
Cannot believe I missed such a simple error! *sigh* Thank you very much for that! I feel really stupid now! Heh

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your foreach loop with the following, i had a similar problem once where white space was creating logic errors, it's worth a shot.

```
foreach( $img_headers as $new_header )
{
    header( trim($new_header), TRUE );
}
```